# Gaonic correspondence with Kiev

Tags: history, responsa, geonim

In a lecture [here](http://www.meirtv.co.il/site/content_idx.asp?idx=13027&cat_id=3738) (@ 4:25) the speaker claims that we have responsa from Gaonim sent to Kiev, Ukraine.

My hunch is that he is (mistakenly) referring to R. [Moshe of Kiev](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_of_Kiev), a contemporary of [Rabbeinu Tam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbeinu_Tam) (12th century).

Does anyone know of any such responsa from the **Gaonic** era?

Comment: Is this possibly related to the Kievian Letter?

Comment: Good guess, but only a minority’s opinion -AFAIK- believes that the letter was sent *from* Kiev. Thanks though.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel also the speaker refers to “תשובות” which the Kievian letter is definitely not.

Comment: IIRC R Gershom learned in yeshivah by the end of the Gaonic period and settled in Constantinople for a while, which is close to Southern Ukraine. Jews definitely lived in Kiev back then (and even Khazar Jews as well) so why wouldn't we expect there to be letters to and from Babylon from the Diaspora including Kiev? Some hold the Kievian letter was sent to Kiev. But either way, to or from, if one side sent it, then we expect someone should have sent one back? :)

Comment: @DavidKenner 1. I didn’t know R. Gershom ever settled (or traveled all to) Constantinople. I’d appreciate if you can find some more info. on that. 2. There may have been Jews in Kiev at the time, but that they were learned I find more surprising and it’s something I’d like to get more info. on. Learned correspondence between Kiev and other communities is something I’d imagine I would’ve heard/read about. 3. I misspoke in my earlier comment; should say “...the letter was sent *to* Kiev”.

Comment: Try contacting https://ukrainianjewishencounter.org/en/contact-us/

Comment: There was a letter from the Gaonic period describing a visitor from Russia to Eretz Yisrael passing through Salonica. Not sure if there's anything else. https://archive.org/details/cu31924082467980/page/n195/mode/2up https://hebrew.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/fragments/full/MS_HEB_e_74_72a.jpg

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you for this. Although my understanding is that the Russian visitor was in Salonica and his *relative*, from Jerusalem was now also visiting in Salonica (see Vol. 1 pg. 165).

Comment: @Harel13 Funny you referred to this book; just came across a copy of it for sale in the FB Seforim group. Simana milsa?

Comment: Having looked further into the subject, it seems there are a number of sources that attest to a Jewish community in Kievan Rus' in the 10th-15th centuries, but only one responsa-type letter, that of Rabbi Moshe of Kiev. If that's what Rabbi Cherki was referring to, I don't think it was a mistaken reference.

Comment: Shmuel ben Ali who received the letter was indeed a Gaon - one of the last. Don't forget that periodization (the process of dividing history into periods) is largely an artifical science (if you can call it such). To 12th century Jews there might not have been much awareness of "the turn of the era". In some places people still turned to the Geonim for higher halachic authority.